# Should every React component have it's own slice, when using createEntityAdapter?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, normalizr

I'm using Redux-tookit's `createSlice` and `createEntityAdapter` with normalized data.

This is a typical blog app with (posts, comments, users) - Entities

Usually, before using `createEntityAdapter` I would:

1. Fetch, normalize and store data in `postsSlice`
   So my postSlice `state` would look something like this:
   `blogPosts: {entities: {posts: {}, users:{}, comments: {}}, ids:[]}`
2. Get `id`'s from `postsSlice`'s state to `Posts` component
3. Pass comment/user `id`'s from `Posts` down to children - `Comment` `User` components, where they would get data using passed `id`'s with selectors connected to parent's `postSlice` state

```
const postsAdapter = createEntityAdapter();

const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState: postsAdapter.getInitialState(),

  reducers: {
    setPosts: (state, { payload }) =>
      postsAdapter.setAll(state, payload.entities.posts),
  },
});
```

---

**The problem is:**

- When using `createEntityAdapter`
  Since we're using `createEntityAdapter.getInitialState()` we get the same initialState `{entities: {} ids: []}` pattern in every slice.
- And this doesn't allow to have initialState like I had before:
  `blogPosts: {entities: {posts: {}, users:{}, comments: {}}, ids:[]}`

***Should every component (`Posts`, `User`, `Comment`) have it's own slice/reducer and fetch it's own piece of data with thunk from the same endpoint?***

**So that:** *(according the createEntityAdapter.getInitialState() pattern)*

- `postSlice` state would just contain post Entity - `entities: {posts: {}, ids:[]}`
- `commentSlice` state - comments Entity - `entities: {comments: {}, ids:[]}`
- *etc...*

Comment: My personal preference is to have an `entities` slice with properties for each entity type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. **There has never been a 1:1 association between components and Redux state structure**.  Instead, you should [organize your state in terms of your data types and update logic](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/basic-reducer-structure#basic-state-shape), and components should access and re-shape that data for their own needs as necessary.

Note that there *are* [multiple ways to approach structuring that data in the store even if it's being normalized](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape).  For example, you could have each data type as its own top-level slice, or have a shared `entities` reducer with each of those types nested inside.